# Why does Jenkins consider batch command failed when it succeeds?

Tags: node.js, jenkins, npm, cmd

I am executing the Windows batch command

```
ng test --code-coverage
```

on **Jenkins** which is installed on **Windows**.

The command is working and the tests are done, but at the end I get these messages:

```
TOTAL: 32 FAILED, 60 SUCCESS

TOTAL: 32 FAILED, 60 SUCCESS

TOTAL: 32 FAILED, 60 SUCCESS

[33m13 05 2020 21:07:58.537:WARN [launcher]: [39mChromeHeadless was not killed in 2000 ms, sending SIGKILL.

Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Code coverage detected 32 failed test cases and for that reason `ng` exited with an exit code greater 0 for failure. This non-zero exit code is passed by `cmd.exe` executing the command line to Jenkins and so Jenkins interprets the build step as not successfully output. You could use `ng test --code-coverage & exit /B 0` to always exit the command line with exit code `0` for success to have the build step always successful even on test cases failed. Note: `call ng test --code-coverage & exit /B 0` must be used if `ng` is a batch file with name `ng.bat` or `ng.cmd`.

Comment: @mofi Yes, I know about the failed but I wanted even with the failed tests to pursue and with ng test --code-coverage & exit /B 0 it workes, thank you for the help